# Error with preamble – the preamble for my homework doesnt even compile

Tags: math-mode, preamble

I have huge problems and I feel like I am going in circles now for a while. For my homework, I have to work with the math-packages, but nothing seems to work. 
I am working with TeXstudio (I could work with overleaf though, if that should make things easier).
So my question is, how do I make my preamble work, so I can use all the math-modus packages I have listed.

I have to use:

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

best regards and a big thanks!

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%PACKAGES%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: please provide a small test document and show the error that you get. It is hard to say anything just from the fragment you have shown.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there are no more errors that the showed, load `amssymb` before that  `MnSymbol` and `amsfonts`. Otherwise, you will have and error because  the command `\centerdot` is already defined.

From the first page of the MnSymbol manual:

> **Interference with other packages**. The MnSymbol package is **incompatible with the `amssymb` and `amsfonts` packages**. It automatically loads the `amsmath` and `textcomp` packages. If you want to pass options to these packages you can either put the corresponding `\usepackage` command before the `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` or you can include the options in the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: Thanks alot, i now changed it to this. %%%%%%%%%%%%%PACKAGES%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}


\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks]{hyperref}

Comment: Now i got this mistake though: File `parskip.sty' not found. \usepackage

Comment: @MVill Probably because is not installed

Comment: Hi, thats greate. i googled, but that didnt really helped me, i thought i would install packages by using \usepackage. How would i install then the packages?

Comment: also note: it has worked before, well until it didnt. and even when i used the bottom "back" it still didnt work.

Comment: \usepackage{whaterver} only load  whaterver.sty file that should be already installed in a searchable path of your hard disk.  The method of install packages is different in each OS and LaTeX distribution (usually MikTeX in Windows and TeXLive in Linux, but also could be the opposite).

Comment: Until you understand what are you doing, I advice you to start with a minimal document (`\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}`), and then add things only one by one,  checking if each addition have spoiled the document or you can pass to the next level of complexity.